# "Enter the Fairies" after a sudden clatter or crash?

Tags: etymology, phrases, interjections, humor, scottish-english

In my family, who originate from Scotalnd, people cry "enter the fairies!" if something has caused a sudden crash, smash  or clatter.
I am guessing it comes from a stage direction, such as from Midsummer nights dream, but I cannot find any reference which requires there to be a crash and I don't know why a crash/smash/collape triggers the interjection.
IS it just our family who says this? 
Nevertheless its fun to say and more original than "taxi" which is heard in bars all over Australia in response to a dropped beer glass.

Comment: 29 July 1943: "[ENTER THE FAIRIES.](http://trove.nla.gov.au/ndp/del/article/38546611?searchTerm=%22Enter%20the%20Fairies%22&searchLimits=) At a north Australian base RAAF officers form a burlesque ballet. The ballerina about to take off is a Wing Commander. (Department of Air photo.)"

Comment: None of the [42 instances in Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Enter+the+Fairies%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22Enter+the+Fairies%22&start=40&tbm=bks) (less than half of which are "legible in context") reflect OP's context - so we can reasonably say even if *some* other families have copied it, there haven't been that many.

Answer (score 8):

**It's sarcastic.** Fairies are supposed to be sylph-like and subtle, and such a crash is anything but.

*Enter the Fairies* sounds like a stage direction, but it doesn't appear in Shakespeare. Fairly close are

> Enter, from opposite sides, a Fairy, and PUCK — *A Midsummer Night's Dream* Act 2 Sc. 1
>
> Enter SIR HUGH EVANS, disguised as before; PISTOL,
> as Hobgoblin; MISTRESS QUICKLY, ANNE PAGE, and
> others, as Fairies, with tapers — *Merry Wives of Windsor* Act 5 Sc. 5

However, it does appear in [*The Maydes Metamorphosis*](ftp://ibiblio.org/pub/docs/books/gutenberg/1/0/3/8/10388/10388-8.txt), published around 1600 and of uncertain authorship:

> Enter the Fairies, singing and dancing.

Comment: I don't know when it was first published, but an anonymous 1600 publication of *The Maydes Metamorphosis* is the only result in [Early English Books Online](http://eebo.chadwyck.com/home). [This](http://www.bookrags.com/ebooks/10388/50.html) says it "may be an early work of John Day". [This](http://www.freefictionbooks.org/books/c/16092-a-collection-of-old-english-plays-volume-1?start=42) says "usually attributed to [John] Lilly". [This](http://bit.ly/GYZ9ef) says it's "attributed to J. Lilly or J. Day".

Comment: Good! Fairies could also be malicious if not treated properly, I wonder if that could influence it. Though, it probably is just sarcastic.

Comment: This makes me think of Gilbert & Sullivan's _Iolanthe_, where the fairies in their opening chorus sing "Tripping hither, tripping thither, nobody knows why or whither". At one point during the chorus the music for "We are dainty little fairies, ever singing ever dancing" is anything but dainty.

Comment: Except that the fairies are coming in to create pandemonium and to tease and confound Demetrius and Lysander. So I think the crash should be taken literally.

Answer (score 0):

I interpreted the phrase to mean that fairies are being blamed for the sound, like tripping the person carrying the item that was dropped, or knocking it out of their hand. Or that the sound acts like a signal to fairies to enter a home or room, as if they cannot enter where no mistakes happen. But I don't know for certain, either way.